# FaceTime and keeping track of call log

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is it possible For a particular user, a log of calls should be maintained,with date,time,person called, duration of call etc?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't interact with the phone/facetime software via the official SDK.

There is the [Core Telephony](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) which will allow you to detect if a phone call active. But this only works if you app is active. Also you can't get that much info of the phone call. Just the state and the call id (which is not the number being called).